# Printing a Record multiple times in PHP and MySql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I am trying to create a webpage that does a simple query of a table and displays the table to a page, but with one complex twist that has got me confused. Here are the column names and one example record from the table separated by commas:

```
R_ID ,  B_ID ,  R_No ,  RoomName , showers , eyewashPlumbed , EyewashBottles  
1 , 609 ,   609 ,   Hazardous Waste Shed ,  1   ,   1    ,  1
```

I need to print each row of this table, but also print multiple rows  if either showers, eyewashPlumbed, or EyewashBottles is greater than 0. For example, I would print this row three times. If showers was 0 I would only print it two times (one for eyewashPlumbed, one for EyewashBottles, and 0 for showers). If showers was 2 I would print it 4 times, etc.

The code I'm using to print is as follows:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)): ?> 
    <tr>
    <td><?php print $row["B_ID"];?></td> 
    <td><?php print $row["R_No"];?></td> 
    <td><?php print $row["RoomName"];?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["Showers"];?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["eyewashPlumbed"];?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["EyewashBottles"];?></td>  
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to interrupt the while loop in order to print the same row multiple times. It goes onto the next row as it pulls from the mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: You aren't mentioning the issue at all.

Comment: we're not a coders-for-hire service. you've listed requirements, but haven't mentioned what your problem is. if it's an inability to write this yourself, then sorry.. that's not what we're here for. try http://php.net/if and http://php.net/for

Comment: I did a really bad job of posting this question. Let me edit it, and try again. This was my first post, I'm still trying to get a hang of the layout of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should switch to PDO / mysqli, but with your current code it would be something like (for `showers` as in your example):

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)):
  $count = 2 + $row["showers"];
  for ($i = 0; $i < $count)
  {
?> 
    <tr>
    <td><?php print $row["Date"];?></td> 
    <td><?php print $row["Inspector1"];?></td> 
    <td><?php print $row["Inspector2"];?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["Building_Name"];?></td>
    <td><?php print $row["Room"];?></td>
    <td><?php print ($i + 1);?></td>  
    </tr>
<?php
  }
endwhile;
?>
```

You probably want to change `$row["shower_no"]` to something like `$i + 1` as that column does not appear in your database.

Comment: I accepted your answer as the chosen answer because it helped me reach the conclusion I needed, even though I didn't use the exact code you posted. This was mostly because I worded the question weirdly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variety of rules

I would handle this problem like this:

```
<?php 

function printRow($row=array(), $times=1) {
    for($i=0; $i<$times; $i++) {
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>{$row["Date"]}</td> 
        <td>{$row["Inspector1"]}</td> 
        <td>{$row["Inspector2"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["Building_Name"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["Room"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["shower_no"]}</td>  
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    switch(true) {
        case ($row['eyewashPlumbed']>0 or $row['EyewashBottles']>0):
            printRow($row, 3); // print 3 times
            break;
        case ($row['showers']==0): // print 2 times
            printRow($row, 2);
            break;
        default: // default print 1 time only
            printRow($row, 1);
    }
}
?>
```