# Convert from date to day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where dates are stored in YYYY-MM-DD format. Is there an SQL query or a simple method using only PHP or javascript that I can use to get the calendar day (Monday, Tues, etc) from the YYYY-MM-DD date?

I tried searching the site for examples, but they all use functions or libraries that are exclusive to Java or C or something.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm using MySQL for my rdbms. Also, I'm not sure if it matters, but I use phpMyAdmin to administrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS but your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363406/printing-a-record-multiple-times-in-php-and-mysql) was MySQL.  If you are using MySQL, then you can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
select date_format(sysdate(), '%W')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4794), just replace `sysdate()` with your date column

Answer (score 0):

This is in SQL Server

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, GETDATE())
```

returns Monday (today is Monday)

Answer (score 0):

```
select datename(dw,getdate()) --Friday

select datepart(dw,getdate()) --6
```

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, %W)
```

**MSSQL**

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, date_column)
```

**Oracle**

```
SELECT to_char(date_column, 'DAY')
```